# Niemark's theorem - simulating POVMs with PVMs

Tags: measurement, povm, state-discrimination

I am having trouble understanding Niemark's theorem from books (e.g watrous). [The wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM) is clearer but most calculations are not justified. I want to contruct the PVM associated with [the state discrimination POVM](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13426/what-are-examples-of-non-trivial-povm-measurements). Can someone explain to me where does the expression for ${\displaystyle {\sqrt {F_{?}}}={\sqrt {\frac {2|\langle \varphi |\psi \rangle |}{1+|\langle \varphi |\psi \rangle |}}}|\gamma \rangle \langle \gamma |}$ come from where ${\displaystyle |\gamma \rangle ={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2(1+|\langle \varphi |\psi \rangle |)}}}(|\psi \rangle +e^{i\arg(\langle \varphi |\psi \rangle )}|\varphi \rangle ).}$? and why $U_{UQSD}$ outputs what it does ?

Comment: it's help to make the post self-contained by including what $\sqrt F$ and $U_{UQSD}$ are. Also, what exactly do you find unclear in the cited explanations?

Comment: In the cited explanations, the details of the calculations are omitted and only the results are shown. What I don't understand is how do they get the formulas above. And If possible I would like to see an explicit application of niemark theorem (by constructing a PVM from an explicit POVM)

Comment: To get this expression for $\sqrt{F_?}$ you just diagonalize $F_?$ and take the square root of the eigenvalues. This is the canonical square root of a positive semidefinite operator. $|\gamma\rangle$ is then the eigenvector with nonzero eigenvalue. $U_\text{UQSD}$ is defined as in the third equation in the subsection "Post-measurement state", just replace the appropriate operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tl;dr of how to go from a given POVM to a PVM is the following:

1. Take your state on which you do the measurement to a larger Hilbert space using a linear isometry $A$.
2. Do a projective measurement in the ancilla registers of the larger Hilbert space.

For a POVM with elements $\{E_i\}$ where $\sum_i E_i = I$, consider the operator

$$A = \sum_i U\sqrt{E_i}\otimes \vert i\rangle,$$

where $U$ is an arbitrary unitary. Note that you have a second unitary freedom in defining the basis of the ancilla system i.e. you can replace all the states $\vert i\rangle$ with $U'\vert i\rangle$ for some other unitary $U'$ and everything that follows still works.

You can work out that $A^\dagger A = I$ i.e. $A$ is an isometry.

Having taken your quantum state to a larger Hilbert space using $A$, you can now do a projective measurement. The PVM elements $\{\Pi_i\}$ are given by $\Pi_i = I\otimes \vert i\rangle\langle i\vert$, which obviously satisfy the requirements of a PVM. Since $E_i = A^\dagger (I\otimes \vert i\rangle\langle i\vert)A$, we have that the post-measurement probabilities are correct i.e.

$$\mathrm{Tr}(E_i\rho) =\mathrm{Tr}(\Pi_i (A\rho A^\dagger)).$$

The right hand side is manifestly a composition of the isometry followed by a projective measurement.

---

Following the notation from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM), for state discrimination between two states, you have a POVM with elements $\{F_\psi, F_\phi, F_?\}$.

You first find these three POVM elements (see [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/35282/how-can-one-derive-the-povm-to-unambiguously-discriminate-between-0-rangle-an/35299#35299) for how). Next, take the square roots of those elements and append an ancilla register in order to construct the required isometry $A$.

It is notationally cumbersome to write $A$ out so I will omit the explicit answer you desire but hopefully you understand how to get there.

Once you have $A$, you do the projective measurement on the ancilla registers and this implements the POVM.