# What's the structure of the measurement $\mu$ that optimally discriminates an ensemble $\{(p_i,\rho_i)\}_i$?

Tags: measurement, state-discrimination

As discussed *e.g.* in [this post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4172/55), given two states $\rho$ and $\sigma$, the measurement that allows to optimally discriminate between them (*i.e.* the measurement providing the highest average probability of figuring out which of the two states the observer was given) is the one projective measurement corresponding to the eigenstates of $\rho-\sigma$. Or more generally of $p\rho-(1-p)\sigma$ if there is a known prior probability $p$ of receiving $\rho$.

Geometrically, as discussed *e.g.* [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9356/55), this result can be understood as saying that the optimal POVM corresponds to the direction (in the Bloch representation) $p\mathbf v_\rho-(1-p)\mathbf v_\sigma$, with $\mathbf v_\rho$ Bloch vector corresponding to $\rho$.
For example, for $p=1/2$, fixing $\rho=|+\rangle\!\langle+|$, and computing the measurement optimally discriminating $\rho$ from $\sigma_p=p |0\rangle\!\langle0| + (1-p) |1\rangle\!\langle1|$ varying $p$, we get the following:

[image]

where we are looking at the plane of the Bloch sphere spanned by the $Z$ and $X$ directions, and the black arrows correspond to $\rho$ and $\sigma_p$, and the red arrows to the associated optimal measurement.

Consider now the case where we want to discriminate between more than two states. Given an ensemble of states $\rho_i$ with prior probabilities $p_i$, this amounts to the POVM $\mu$ that maximises the discrimination probability
$$p_{\rm disc}(\mu) \equiv \sum_i p_i \langle\mu_i, \rho_i\rangle.$$
For ensembles with more than two states, this won't in general have a nice closed expression.
Nevertheless, there might be a way to understand how the structure of the resulting optimal measurement relates to that of the given ensemble. Is there any result to this end?